# Finding the definite integral for the limit

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I am a second year CS student that is taking Calculus 2 classes. I've been looking quite some time to solve this limit problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^p + \dots + (3n)^p}{(n+1)^{p+1}} $$

I've tried using Riemann's integral method to solve this (Since supposedly it is the intended method) but still the steps to finding the answer aren't quite right. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^{p + 1} }}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{3n} {k^p }  = \left( {\frac{{3n}}{{n + 1}}} \right)^{p + 1} \frac{1}{{3n}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{3n} {\left( {\frac{k}{{3n}}} \right)^p } 
$$ Can you finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is pointed by @Gary, you can rewrite the formula as follows:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl(\frac{3n}{n+1}\biggr)^{p+1}
  \frac{1}{3n}\sum_{k=1}^{3n} \biggl(\frac{k}{3n}\biggr)^p.
$$

Consider the integral of $x^n$ on $[0,1]$, divide the interval into $3n$ subintervals $[0,1/3n]$, $[1/3n,2/3n]$, $\ldots$, $[(3n-1)/3n,1]$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 x^p\,dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{3n} \frac{1}{3n}\biggl(\frac{k}{3n}\biggr)^p = \frac{1}{p+1}.
$$
Hence the final result is $\frac{3^{p+1}}{p+1}$.

Comment: Yes this seems like a good way to understand the problem with solution. Would this mean by this logic that the answer to this question here $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^p + 3^p + \dots + (2n+1)^p}{(n)^{p+1}} $$ is $\frac{2^{p+1}}{p+1}$ ?

Comment: I think it is $2^p/(p+1)$@TKIndividual

Comment: If possible by your end, could You explain the answer?

Comment: @TKIndividual you could use the [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) theorem.

Comment: Or you can calculate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^p+3^p+\cdots +(2n-1)^p}{n^{p+1}}$. Using the same method, you can regard it as an integral $\frac12\int_0^2 x^p\,dx = \frac{2^p}{p+1}$.